# Mapbox/Leaflet map rotation

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

The app uses mapbox with leaflet Js.
Theres a callback for the location-found event and we set a marker with user's location.

I'd the like map to rotate according with the user location, like a compass.

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaflet doesn't support map rotation (yet), or perspective, for that matter. See [bug #268](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/268).

I did some work for this in the [`rotate` code branch](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/tree/rotate), but that is still kinda experimental and breaks easily. I don't think it will make it to the Leaflet core, as WebGL is a more promising (and less messy in the long run) way of achieving better results at map rotation than CSS transforms (which is what the `rotate` branch is about).

Comment: Thank you Ivan, you know if mapbox native APIs support it?

Comment: Looks like it does. Do check out https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.rotateTo and related documentation about mapbox GL.

Answer (score 0):

MapBox has a "bearing" option for that. Here https://jsfiddle.net/rwnfbu7c/1/ is a example

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    // camera options properties - https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/camera/
    center: [34, 28],
    bearing: -65, // bearing in degrees
    zoom: 2
});
```